# Avoiding MaxLocksPerFile via odbc connection to MS Access

Tags: ms-access, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

Due to "circumstances beyond my control"<sup>tm</sup>, I am using sqlalchemy with an MS Access backend. I'm having an issue that the following code:

```
def delete_imports(self, files_imported_uid):
    table_name = 'my_table'
    delete_raw = self.meta.tables[table_name].delete()
    self.engine.execute(delete_raw.where(
        self.meta.tables[table_name].c.files_imported_uid == files_imported_uid)
        )
```

throws a "File sharing lock count exceeded." error with large tables.  The statement generated is just:

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE my_table.files_imported_uid = ?
```

with a parameter of the uid. The statement is then executed via pyodbc. [MSDN provided](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815281) some suggestions to get around the problem, before informing me that they won't work if the database is on a Novell NetWare server, which it is.

Is there a known work around that I can use (preferably at the sqlalchemy layer), or do I need to create some ugly hack that selects the top 9,000 records at a time to delete and loops until finished?

Comment: I wonder if you found this:http://www.intersoft.co.nz/support_technicalbulletins/tsb1009.htm ?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not in the IT department and so have no control over the network share setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked into this, sqlalchemy can't support 'Top' on deletes (eliminating the simple option of ordering and deleting the top 9000 each time till the whole delete is finished) so I gave in and just deleted each line individually. Not ideal, but given that:

1) This operation is only performed once a month
2) Deletes are pretty quick anyway
3) I'm the main user of the application...

it didn't seem worth coding a more efficient work around.

Answer (score 0):

[PRB: Error "3050 Could Not Lock File" When You Connect to a Jet Database on a Novell Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305995/)

Now option 1 requires admin access to HKLM.  Option 2 is Access specific and I have no idea if those would work in sqlalchemy .